# oauth2 implementation in the Play scala web-socket

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, oauth-2.0, playframework-2.3

I have developed the web-socket using the Play2.3 scala and I am trying to implement the oauth2 in the Play scala web-socket using the [oauth-provider](https://github.com/nulab/scala-oauth2-provider).

**Code snippet of web-socket:**

```
object LoginWS {
  def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new LoginWS(out))
}

class LoginWS(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case json_req: JsObject =>
        val login_status : String = "Success"
        out ! Json.toJson(JsObject(Seq("login_status" -> JsString(login_status))))
  }
}

object WebSocketController extends Controller {

  def login = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    out =>
      LoginWS.props(out)
  }

}
```

**Code snippet of oauth2 for REST service:**

I have used the "[scala-oauth2-provider-slick](https://github.com/davidseth/scala-oauth2-provider-slick)" sample for the oauth2 implementation.

```
trait MyOAuth extends OAuth2Provider {
  override val tokenEndpoint: TokenEndpoint = MyTokenEndpoint
}

object OAuth2Controller extends Controller with MyOAuth {

  val cats = TableQuery[CatsTable] 
  implicit val catFormat = Json.format[Cat]

  def accessToken = Action.async { implicit request =>
    issueAccessToken(new Oauth2DataHandler())
  }

  def list = Action.async { implicit request =>
    authorize(new Oauth2DataHandler()) { authInfo =>
      DBAction { implicit rs =>
        Ok(toJson(cats.list))
      }.apply(request)
    }
  }
}
```

How do I implement the oauth2 in the above web-socket code?

anybody know, How to implement the oauth2 for the above web-socket?

**UPDATED:**

I tried to implement the oauth and web socket:

**Code snippet:**

```
  def login = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
      authorize(new Oauth2DataHandler()) { authInfo =>
      val user = authInfo.user // User is defined on your system
      println(user.toString())
    }
  }
```

**Got the below issue:**

```
1) polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : [A]scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result] required: Either[play.api.mvc.Result,play.api.mvc.WebSocket.HandlerProps] (which expands to) Either[play.api.mvc.Result,akka.actor.ActorRef ⇒ akka.actor.Props]

2) type mismatch; found : Unit required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2Provider provides protectedResource instance, so you can call directly handleRequest method to authorize in your WebSocket controller.
Client send access token through HTTP header or query parameter.

I recommend you use tryAcceptWithActor intead acceptWithActor.
Because you need to return bad request if user send invalid access token.

```scala
object LoginWS {
  def props(user: User)(out: ActorRef) = Props(new LoginWS(user, out))
}

object WebSocketController extends Controller extends MyOAuth {

  def login = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    Future.successful {
      (protectedResource.handleRequest(request, new Oauth2DataHandler())).map {
        case Left(e) => e match {
          case e: OAuthError if e.statusCode == 400 => Left(BadRequest.withHeaders(responseOAuthErrorHeader(e)))
          case e: OAuthError if e.statusCode == 401 => Left(Unauthorized.withHeaders(responseOAuthErrorHeader(e)))
        }
        case Right(authInfo) => Right(LoginWS.props(authInfo.user) _)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure whether this code can compile.
But I have written similar code using this library.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I add this line, I got the "not enough arguments for method map: (implicit executor: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[play.api.mvc.Result,akka.actor.ActorRef => akka.actor.Props]]. Unspecified value parameter executor." Error.

Comment: Can you please check the below issue. Please help me on this to proceed further. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/q/37183156/1584121

Comment: If you get a time, please look on this issue. Thanks! - http://stackoverflow.com/q/37183156/1584121

Comment: I just noticed your comment now. I have never used Slick but I think you just  use Join feature of Slick in select query.